# ActiveMQ error for .Net Channel was inactive for too long: ssl://sampleUrl:443/?transport.servername=samplename

Tags: c#, .net-core, activemq-artemis

I tried to connect to activemq broker instance which I had setup locally from a .net core application and it worked without any issues.

Now, when I am connecting to the **activemq-artemis** instance present at a different server from a .Net Core (.Net 6.0) application over ssl I get the error "Channel was inactive for too long: ssl://servername:443/?transport.servername=samplename"

I have imported the ssl certificate in trusted store using certmgr in my windows machine.
I have tried connecting to the instance from jmeter from my instance and it works, so there isnt a network issue.

If I append transport.useInactivityMonitor=false in the brokerUri the error changes to "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Any insights to resolve this?

```
    using Apache.NMS;
    using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;
    using ISession = Apache.NMS.ISession;
 
    var brokerUri = "activemq:ssl://servername:443";
    brokerUri += "?transport.serverName=samplename";

    IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
    _connection = factory.CreateConnection("sampleuser", "samplepassword");
    _connection.Start();
    _session = _connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
```

The above code fails at

`_connection.Start();`

Exception Stack Trace:

Comment: Are you sure that the port is correct? The default activemq port is as far as I know not 443

Comment: Looks like the connection completes.  Error indicates no data is being sent over the connection so a timeout occurs.

Comment: yes the port is correct as I can send a message using the same port from Jmeter, and talking to the team managing the broker also confirmed the port number.

Comment: there should not be a time as it fails instantaneously at _connection.Start, honestly I don't understand either why is this happening